# Failed to return after decimal value while concenating '$' sing before flot value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I am looking after quick solution however it is, I can change the logic in the suggested way:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(id INT, exposure FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #tmpTable
SELECT 1, 171325.69

SELECT '$ '+cast(exposure AS VARCHAR) Exposure FROM #tmpTable
--OR-- 
SELECT concat('$ ',exposure) Exposure FROM #tmpTable

DROP TABLE #tmpTable

--Output
Exposure
$ 171326

--Desired
$ 171326.69
```

I think, the way is not absolute so, please help me on this to resolve.

Comment: What's the problem with `SELECT concat('$ ',exposure) Exposure FROM #tmpTable`? You may need a CAST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(id INT, exposure NUMERIC(18,2))
INSERT INTO #tmpTable
SELECT 1, 171325.69

SELECT '$ '+cast(exposure AS VARCHAR) Exposure FROM #tmpTable
--OR-- 
SELECT concat('$ ', exposure) Exposure FROM #tmpTable

DROP TABLE #tmpTable
```

Having your table as `NUMERIC` will solve your problem and return the expected result using both methods.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working fine so it is called solution from the root :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), exposure))
FROM #tmpTable
```

Answer (score 0):

using changing datatype of column exposure to decimal then

```
            cREATE TABLE #tmpTable(id INT, exposure DECIMAL(8,2))
            INSERT INTO #tmpTable
            SELECT 1, 171325.69
            select * from #tmpTable

            SELECT '$ '+cast(exposure AS VARCHAR) Exposure FROM #tmpTable
            --OR-- 
            SELECT concat('$ ',exposure) Exposure FROM #tmpTable
```

If dont want to chagne datatype to decimal then use below query :

```
            SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), exposure))
            FROM #tmpTable
```

Comment: That is exactly what I got from the above answers by Tim & Jens, Anyway, thanks for your effort.